# How to fix flicker when using Webkit transforms & transitions in iOS 6

Tags: ipad, css, ios6

We've built an HTML5 app for the ipad that uses Webkit transforms and transitions for animations. In the past we have had to use `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to enable hardware acceleration to prevent animations from flickering and to appear smooth. We have updated to iOS 6 and this technique no longer seems to work. Is there a new way to invoke hardware accelation in iOS 6 for animations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```css
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: I replaced all instances where i used `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` with `-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` and it did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Apple has changed safari in iOS6, so that [using translate3d doesn't automatically trigger GPU acceleration](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers). I think people are playing with different approaches right now to figure out how to make this happen.

Comment: Why would they do that?? So frustrating! If you do come across any work arounds could you let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing this by applying translate3d(0, 0, 0) to every element inside of what I was transforming.

```
.content * { -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0); }
```